# UML diagrams when using multiple languages

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I would like to ask what the case if of a class diagram and sequence diagrams when using multiple languages? For instance let us say that we use Android (which is JAVA) and combine that with PHP because of some database thing.

Should my class diagram have both my android (java) classes and PHP classes? And can I show in my sequence diagrams the interact these two languages have with each other in my app?

Comment: This is likely not a diagraming question.

Comment: Thanks for the link Geert, and sorry Thomas if it is not sounding like a diagramming question, but that is the intention however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding Geerts correct answer in the marked duplicate, your class design is independent from any language or diagram. When designing a system on class level you concentrate on function. In your case you have different sub-systems (here client and server parts). Usually you will package them differently and in a later stage you will transform them to different codings (in Java and PHP). In that way you will create perspectives that highlight the inner parts of the sub-systems as well as their inter-communication. This highlighting starts with the right packaging and is extended by using the appropriate number of different class diagrams.

Comment: So in theory it depends on what system you are building and basically up to you whether you put them together or not according to which option is best?

Comment: This is an architectural decision on who to cut your system. It's definitely not a diagramming question.